# Creating Malloc and Free function to test a sorting algorithm - In MIPS

Tags: mips

How does one create a malloc and free function in MIPS assembly language and use it to test a specific sorting algorithm(preferably heap sort). We must also use sbrk to call the malloc function.

Any form of help or ideas would be much appreciated.
Thanks